# In Visual Studio why does a double click on a panel make a paint event? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, panels

I'm in VS IDE and when I double click a panel, it generates a paint event instead of a click event. I've tried other controls and they work fine.

Also, this just started happening today. I know that I can go to properties/events and double click the "click" field and it will produce the desired result, but it's a pain in the butt.

forgot to say... I'm using VS 2015

any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean it creates a paint event handler.  It is just the default for that control since a click event would be used far less often on a container control

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for the answer. I didn't know that. Guess I've never tried to double click a panel before <smile>. If that's the default behavior, that's fine. Put what you posted in an answer and I will mark it the accepted solution.

Comment: I just explained why no click variation is the default - I have no idea why they chose the paint event since I didnt write it.  (But if I had.....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DefaultEventAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to specify the default event for a component.  The docs for [`Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and presumably the other WinForms components) don't seem to show the value for the default event attribute, but if you look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Panel.cs,0c484d0cc724caad) (or decompile it yourself), you can see the value there:

```cs
[
ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch),
DefaultProperty("BorderStyle"),
DefaultEvent("Paint"),
Docking(DockingBehavior.Ask),
Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.PanelDesigner, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign),
SRDescription(SR.DescriptionPanel)
]
public class Panel : ScrollableControl {
```

I suppose the designers for each component pick the most frequently used event as the default, otherwise the base [`Control`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9884211b7ff61817) class defines a default of `Click`:

```cs
[
ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch),
DefaultProperty("Text"),
DefaultEvent("Click"),
Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign),
DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign, "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign),
ToolboxItemFilter("System.Windows.Forms")
]
public partial class Control :
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think I might use something in place of a panel. Or, I will just use the properties/events to add a click event to a panel. Thanks a bunch

Comment: The panel **has** a click event (and DoubleClick, MouseClick and MouseDoubleClick) none of them are the *Default* event (the one created when you dbl click in the designer) because it is a container control - meant to hold/group other things not interact with the user.  @jumper